# Adding an element to vector of pair throws error: Segmentation violation signal

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
namespace detail {

    
    class AdjacencyListGraphBase {
    protected:
        // these are the edges in the graph - each outbound edge comes with a weight
        std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, float>>> edges;

        virtual size_t get_num_nodes() const = 0; // call the derived class to get the number of nodes

    public:
        void add_edge(uint32_t from, uint32_t to, float weight=1.0f);
        void remove_edge(uint32_t from, uint32_t to);
        std::optional<float> get_edge(uint32_t from, uint32_t to) const;

        const std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, float>>& get_edges_starting_at(uint32_t node) const;
    };
}
```

and I want to add an element with the following function:

```
    void detail::AdjacencyListGraphBase::add_edge(uint32_t from, uint32_t to, float weight)
{
    if(!(edges[from][to].first==to)){
        edges[from][to].first = to;
        edges[from][to].second = weight;
    }
}
```

but when I call this function I get the following error: **SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal**. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Do I have to resize the vector edges? Or is there something missing that I don't see?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it depends on what you are passing to your function as "from" and "to" arguments. You may need to resize vector, or use push_back() method if index is greater then vector.size()

Comment: `edges[from][to]` -- Change that to this: `edges.at(from).at(to)`.  If you are going out-of-bounds, you will instead get a `std::out_of_range` error thrown instead of a seg fault.

Comment: Before accessing the value of a position, first check if that's a valid position. For ex.
if( from < edges.size() && to < edges[from].size() &&  !(edges[from][to].first==to)) {}

Comment: Ok thank you! I applied your solution and it worked!